# mybatis:Attribute "resource" must be declared for element type "mapper"

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

Can someone tells me what's wrong with? I spent more than 2days to debug but i still cannot.Is there anything obvious wrong with this setup please. I followed a tutorial form the web.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
    ### Error building SqlSession.
    ### The error may exist in com/test/ProductMapper.xml
    ### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 49; Attribute "resource" must be declared for element type "mapper".
        at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:23)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:35)
        at com.test.TestMybatis.delete(TestMybatis.java:44)
        at com.test.Calltest.main(Calltest.java:18)
    Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 49; Attribute "resource" must be declared for element type "mapper".
        at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.parseConfiguration(XMLConfigBuilder.java:105)
        at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.parse(XMLConfigBuilder.java:88)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:49)
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 49; Attribute "resource" must be declared for element type "mapper".
        at org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.createDocument(XPathParser.java:253)
        at org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.<init>(XPathParser.java:122)
        at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.<init>(XMLMapperBuilder.java:74)
        at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.mapperElement(XMLConfigBuilder.java:310)
        at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.parseConfiguration(XMLConfigBuilder.java:103)
        ... 5 more
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 49; Attribute "resource" must be declared for element type "mapper".
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.addDTDDefaultAttrsAndValidate(XMLDTDValidator.java:1253)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1917)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:763)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1342)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2770)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:347)
        at org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.createDocument(XPathParser.java:251)
        ... 9 more
```

Product Mapper

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE mapper
  PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="com.test.ProductMapper">
 <mapper resource="com/test/ProductMapper.xml"/>  
<typeAlias alias="Product" type="com.test.Product"/> 

    <insert id="insertProduct" parameterClass="Product">  
        insert into product (brand,model,name) values (#{brand},#{model},#{name});  
    </insert> 

    <delete id="deleteFilm"  parameterClass="Product">  
        delete from product where id = #{id}  
    </delete>  
 </mapper>
```

Product POJO

```
package com.test;

public class Product {

    private int id; 
    private String brand;
    private String model; 
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }
    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }
    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }
    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Test Class

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

import org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder;

public class TestMybatis {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    private static final String RESOURCE = "com/test/SqlMapConfig.xml"; 


    public static void test() throws IOException{
        Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(RESOURCE); 
        SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);
        SqlSession session = null; 
        try{
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            //DAO mean Interface class
            ProductMapper mapper=session.getMapper(ProductMapper.class);
            //CRUD
            Product p=new Product();
            p.setName("kee");
            mapper.insertProduct(p);
            session.commit();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public void delete() throws IOException{
        Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(RESOURCE); 
        SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);
        SqlSession session = null; 
        try{
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            //DAO mean Interface class
            ProductMapper mapper=session.getMapper(ProductMapper.class);
            //CRUD
            mapper.deleteProduct(1);
            session.commit();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


       }
}
```

Comment: no one? please i need to fix it as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

Your `mapper` element contains another `mapper`. This is wrong. You should remove `<mapper resource="com/test/ProductMapper.xml"/>` line. It was probably copied from MyBatis configuration file to mapper configuration file.

Please see the appropriate sections about [configuration](https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/configuration.html) and [mapper xml files](https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html) in the documentation.